# Using dpkg-buildpackage to build multiple packages from same source

Tags: compilation, debian, dpkg

I have a source tree that can build two different projects from the same source.  You call make A or make B, and the code is affected by ifdefs and similar using preprocessor variables to make two versions of the output.  I'm looking to make dpkgs for these, and can make one fine, but am unsure of a good way to do this.

Currently I run dpkg-buildpackage, and I get A.deb or similar.  Is there a way to do dpkg-buildpackage -target B so that it would then build a debian package for that project?

Things such as [Creating multiple packages with dpkg-buildpackage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670630/creating-multiple-packages-with-dpkg-buildpackage) seem to refer to having separate source code for the separate projects, which is not the case here.

I am in control of the source code so can make changes there.

Thanks.

Comment: You can set up one rules file to build two separate Debian packages at the same time. But if they are unrelated, this is an abuse of the Debian packaging procedure. It's designed for building multiple related Debian binary packages from a single source.

Comment: Thanks - that is in fact what I did.  They are related, although it's not obvious to me how related they should be for this to be a good course of action.

Comment: Ok, in that case I've added the comment as a formal answer. If it answers your question, then accept it, so that people will know your problem was solved. If you need any further elaboration, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up one rules file to build two separate Debian packages at the same time. But if they are unrelated, this is an abuse of the Debian packaging procedure. It's designed for building multiple related Debian binary packages from a single source.